# Am i been scam or should i pay?

Tags: transaction-fees, fraud, bitcoin-wallet-app, withdrawal

I was contacted on social media. He was going to mine 200 btc for me and I get a profit of $4870. He told me to create a black chain account but we never use it. Instead when I bought the btc he send me a link to put it in for it to be mined which I did . However when it was te to withdraw money I was told I need to make a deposit of 1200 to get the money by Trust Markets • trustmarkets2471@gmail.com which I refuse to pay am I right not to pay?

Comment: This is certainly a scam. Do not send them any money. They were never going to give you anything.

Comment: "If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it probably is a duck." Yeah, it's a scam.